# Google Maps looks like an image

Tags: android, google-maps

I have two Google Maps in my application, which I have implemented in the same way. One is working and one is not. The latter looks like an image and I can't interact with it. I can add markers and move the camera, but the info window doesn't show when I click the marker I can't move it, zoom in and zoom out. It looks like an image, a preview.

Here is the code:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private static Double latitude;
    private static Double longitude;
    private static String title;

    public static MapFragment newInstance(Double mLatitude, Double mLongitude, String mTitle) {
        latitude=mLatitude;
        longitude=mLongitude;
        title=mTitle;
        MapFragment fragment = new MapFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map_details);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.location_icon))
                .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                .title(title));
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(latitude,longitude)).zoom(12f).build();
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition);
        mMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
    }

    public interface OnMapFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onMapFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if you set `liteMode=true` in your xml

Comment: No. I don't have this attribute set.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at XML. There is `liteMode` and when it's set to true it does exactly what you are describing.

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/row_map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            map:liteMode="true"
            map:mapType="none" />
```

Here look at [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/lite)

Comment: No,setting liteMode to false didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing but in code that you posted i see one mistake. To be sure you have to check your imports in the place when you try to use your MapFragment. As I said I guess that in one place it's imported from google pacage and another one from your class. The problem is that the MapFragment that you post here isn't a google MapFragment because you extants it from simple Fragment. To be sure rename your own MapFragment to CustomMapFragment and try to extands from MapFragment or just use it without customize.

Comment: No, I have imported my package everywhere.

Comment: @AndreiP I don't know how this spinnet could work so ok let's make it step by step. At first you can't use the params that you put in method newInstance(...) because it make you field the same for both of your maps. Delete static modify and put your params like this:

     public static MapFragment newInstance(Double mLatitude) {
        MapFragment fragment = new MapFragment();
        fragment.latitude=mLatitude;
        return fragment;
    }